# How to draw points and save the output image in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

I am trying to draw some points with x and y coordinates and save the output to an image file but I couldn't. (It is not necessary to see them on JFrame)
As far as I learned by searching, I can create the drawing and show it on JFrame but I couldn't save this output to a file.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
        final JFrame frm = new JFrame("Points");
        final Panel pnl = new Panel();
        pnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000, 1000));
        frm.setContentPane(pnl);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setVisible(true);
        frm.repaint();
        Image img;
        img = frm.createImage(1000, 1000);
        ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) img, "jpeg", new File("C:/.../p.jpeg"));
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    } catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


public static class Panel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        for (final Point p : CandidatePoints) {
            g.fillRect((int) p.getX() * 10, (int) p.getY() * 10, 20, 20);
        }}
```

Besides, I have tried the popular solution of BufferedImage with ImageIO but in that case I couldn't create a coordinate system instead I got a black rectangle in image file.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(200, 200,
                BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED);

        Graphics2D g2d = bimage.createGraphics();

        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        for (final Point p : CandidatePoints) {
            g2d.fillRect((int) p.getX() * 10, (int) p.getY() * 10, 20, 20);
            ImageIO.write(bimage, "jpeg", new File("C:/.../p.jpeg"));
            g2d.dispose();
        }}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: You should _not_ write the image _inside_ the loop but _after_ the loop, i.e. first fill the image then write and dispose.

Comment: Also, `TYPE_BYTE_INDEXED` does not work well with JPEG.

Comment: You should also be call the `paintComponent`'s super method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need any Swing components to create an image and save it to file.

Here is a small example of drawing circle and saving it into file:

```
public class ImageExample
{
    public static void main ( String[] args ) throws IOException
    {
        final BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage ( 1000, 1000, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB );
        final Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics ();
        graphics2D.setPaint ( Color.WHITE );
        graphics2D.fillRect ( 0,0,1000,1000 );
        graphics2D.setPaint ( Color.BLACK );
        graphics2D.drawOval ( 0, 0, 1000, 1000 );
        graphics2D.dispose ();

        ImageIO.write ( image, "png", new File ( "C:\\image.png" ) );
    }
}
```

You might need to play around with image type if you will need exactly jpeg image on the output.

The reason you get black rectangle is the fact that you do not fill background with anything and JPEG format doesn't support transparent images - if you want your image to be transparent use PNG instead for example. Or you can just fill-in image background with any color you want to be there. Also as it was mentioned in comments - not all image types work well with different output image formats.

Also, just in case - coordinates on all images and components are starting in top-left corner ([0,0] coordinate).

And if you want to save part of your desktop Swing application UI into image file you will need to use methods provided by Swing components to paint them onto graphics, retrieved from image.

Comment: That is what I needed. Thank you,